# Deezer API : get user's favorite genres

Tags: deezer

I'm using the deezer API and I wonder if there is a way to find user's favorite genre ?

The only solution I found is to search for every user's favorite album (https://api.deezer.com/album/105374). But this requires a lots of request !

I wonder if it's possible to get several album details in one time ? (e.g. https://api.deezer.com/album/105374,1053743). Or maybe something else ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to get that information directly. What you can do is to get the top tracks/albums with http://developers.deezer.com/api/user/charts, and look for the genre.

There is no possibility too to get several albums in the same request.

Comment: Thank you but there is no genre in the user/charts API, I need to call albums, one by one.